# How to use BundleWiring.findEntries() on system bundle?

Tags: java, osgi

I am trying to find a set of package names in all OSGi modules by using BundleWiring's findEntries() method. For all other modules, I can simply run

`bundleWiring.findEntries("/" + packageName, "*.class", 2)`

to get the URL's to all classes in that package.

The problem is this approach doesn't work for OSGi System Bundle (bundle 0). Through the classloader I was able to see that the classes I want are in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/x.jar, but how can I find the path to those classes if I am only given System Bundle as a bundle?

The packages are exported in system.packages.extra.mf

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this information?

Comment: I am trying to check for split package problems, manager wants to avoid editing the bundle if both bundles have the exact same package with exact same classes. So when the system bundle and a module bundle conflict I need a way to get all the classes in system bundle package to check against the module bundle package.

Comment: This sounds like something that you should be doing at build-time rather than runtime. In which case you can just look at the JAR files.

Comment: Incidentally in OSGi it's fine for two bundles to have the same packages with the same classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because the system bundle is just the "outside" of OSGi. You can use an arbitrary ClassLoader to load the OSGi Framework, and ClassLoaders don't have a way to iterate the packages or classes that they know about.